# How to get a list of specific records using ASP.NET ObjectDataSource with Repository Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository-pattern, objectdatasource

I am a new ASP.NET Webforms developer. I am learning now how to use `ObjectDataSource` with the Entity Framework and Repository Pattern. What I am struggling with right now is to retrieve a specific list of items from a table using `ObjectDataSource` with the `ListView` Control.

In the Config table in the database, I have 10 records. I would like to retrieve 7 records only. **So how can I do that?** How can I give this list of ids to the `ObjectDataSource` in order to retrieve those 7 records not all of the records?

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvConfigs" runat="server"
                    DataSourceID="odsConfig" DataKeyNames="Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                                <img src="../Assets/images/team/member1.png" alt="">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>
                                        <%#Eval("Value") %>
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                        <%#Eval("Entry") %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <span>No data was returned.</span>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsConfig" runat="server"
                    TypeName="Test.BLL.ConfigBL"
                    DataObjectTypeName="Test.Models.T_Config"
                    SelectMethod="GetConfigs"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here's the code of `SysConfigRepository` class:

```
public class SysConfigRepository : IDisposable, ISysConfigRepository
    {
        //internal variable
        private readonly TestEntities dbContext = new DbdKurdoaEntities();

        public IEnumerable<T_SysConfig> GetSysConfigs()
        {
            return dbContext.T_SysConfig.ToList();
        }

        public T_SysConfig GetSysConfig(int id)
        {
            T_SysConfig sysConfigObj = GetSysConfigs().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
            return sysConfigObj;
        }

        private bool disposedValue = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    dbContext.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposedValue = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Code of `ISysConfigRepository` :

```
public interface ISysConfigRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<T_SysConfig> GetSysConfigs();
        T_SysConfig GetSysConfig(int sysConfigId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do:

```
    public List<T_SysConfig> GetSysConfigs(List<int> ids)
    {
        List<T_SysConfig> sysConfigObjs = GetSysConfigs().ToList();
        List<T_SysConfig> result =(from c1 in sysConfigObjs 
                                    join c2 in ids on c1.Id equals c2
                                    select c1).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Add another method to get a list of configs from a list of IDs

Comment: thanks for your help. You mean I should add this method to my repository class, right?

Comment: Yes, and for the pattern you are following, I think you should add this to your interface as well.

Comment: please mark the answer if it helped - so it helps future visitors as well ;). thx

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I am still trying to figure out how to use this method with my `ObjectDataSource`. How am I going to send the list of Ids to the `ObjectDataSource`? Let us assume we have a list of the following ids: 1, 3, 5, 9.

Comment: I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN that might help you in passing parameters to the SelectMethod.